# Install ROS groovy on Ubuntu ARM

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ubuntu 12.04-LTS-armhf, and my target board is ODROID-XU.
And I want to install ROS groovy on it.
But when I tried to install by 'sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-ros-base' as in the installation tutorial.
It just could not find the package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144401/install-ros-groovy-on-ubuntu-arm/) by [seongyun](https://answers.ros.org/users/12841/seongyun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seongyun](https://answers.ros.org/users/12841/seongyun/) on 2014-03-25**:
I link the tutorial, http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not all packages are necessarily available on arm platforms.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0